# How to describe the sound of the piano when its keys are pressed randomly

Tags: word-request, onomatopoeia

I'm describing a scene in which the father picks up the kid and puts her on the piano. While doing it, a random sound comes out of the piano because some keys were randomly pressed by the kid's body. Now I want to describe the sound and the context to the reader, and put it in the text you know like a script of a play where they put contextual cues within brackets.

> [The piano ........]

*.... keys were randomly pressed*? I don't think so. It's awkward.

Comment: [**cacophony**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cacophony) *- a harsh discordant mixture of sounds*. I seriously doubt there's a specific *verb* meaning "to make a cacophonous sound".

Comment: @FumbleFingers wow an interesting word. Is it OK if I adjust it like _the piano plays in cocophony_ or something?!

Comment: I've never heard the adverbial clause ***in cacophony***, so I'd advise you not to use it. Either work with the noun form, or go for some adjectival construction such as *The father plonked the child down on the piano keys with a cacophonous thump.*

Comment: Native speakers don't normally use ***it*** to refer to "a kid."

Comment: Pianists refer to this sound as a _"Sonata by Rodion Shchedrin."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing some similar research for a song I'm writing. Has "clanging" been suggested yet?

> piano keys clang

From [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clang):

> to make a loud metallic ringing sound
> *anvils clanged*

Answer (score 5):

[The piano roars in protest.]

[The piano groans in protest.]

[The piano cries in protest.]

Comment: Not sure why this is voted -1.  If you're looking for the equivalent of a contextual clue, these are the ones.  Pianos can indeed groan, roar, and cry.

Answer (score 2):

***[Plonk on](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/plonk)*** may suggest the idea:

> - [no object] Play unskilfully on a musical instrument.
>     *‘people plonking around on expensive instruments’*

ODO

Comment: -1 the kid is not playing unskillfully, he's not playing at all. His body has randomly, inadvertently touched some keys. Now, what's your reason for downvoting my answer.

Comment: Read the definition: "play unskilfully" that may apply to kids!

Comment: A piano cannot "plonk on", but [children do "plonk"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=13sR4xW8oqU)  on the piano. Maybe the "the sound of piano keys being plonked", or "bashed" if the resulting sound is noisy and painful to listen..

Comment: @Josh, xxxxxxx, AB a kid can play unskillfully, yes. But that is not what the question is asking. In this question the kid is not playing at all.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a verb that means exactly what you are looking for, but you could use a word like "erupted" to indicate that the noise came on quickly and violently. When combined with @FumbleFinger's suggestion of the word "cacophonous", we could have a sentence like this:

> The piano *erupted* in *cacophonous noise*.

Other potential verbs are *exploded*, *roared*, *burst*, etc.

Answer (score -1):

The piano makes a discordant noise (or sound).

> 1 Disagreeing or incongruous.
>   1.1 (of sounds) harsh and jarring because of a lack of harmony.
>   *‘the singers continued their discordant chanting’*

([Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/discordant))

Discordant

> 1. Not being in accord; conflicting.
> 2. Disagreeable in sound; harsh or dissonant.

([American Heritage](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=Discordant))